# Navigation In Android Fragments

Tags: android, navigation, android-fragments

I tried with Fragments with tabs. I have three tabs in my application,FragA, FragB, FragC.
In FragA Class I have a button. If I clicked the button, then want to navigate to the Class FragNew. How can I do this..

Here is my FragA Class:

```
public class AFragment extends Fragment {

    Button next;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.afragment, container, false);
        next = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "FragmentA Clicked...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return view;

    }

}
```

afragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#85ff34"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Fragment A"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and My FragNew Class is:

```
public class FragNew extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bfragment, container, false);
    }
    }
```

Here is the View of my requirement:

```
MainTabActivity
  ActivityInTab1
    Fragment1 -> Fragment2 -> Fragment3
  ActivityInTab2
    Fragment4
  ActivityInTab3
    Fragment5 -> Fragment6
```

How can I do the Navigation between FragA to FragNew with Maintain the Tabs like TabGroup Activity.

Answer (score 0):

this may helps you for more details [fragments details](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

/**
     * Helper function to show the details of a selected item, either by
     * displaying a fragment in-place in the current UI, or starting a
     * whole new activity in which it is displayed.
     */

```
void showDetails(int index) {
    mCurCheckPosition = index;

    if (mDualPane) {
        // We can display everything in-place with fragments, so update
        // the list to highlight the selected item and show the data.
        getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);

        // Check what fragment is currently shown, replace if needed.
        DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);
        if (details == null || details.getShownIndex() != index) {
            // Make new fragment to show this selection.
            details = DetailsFragment.newInstance(index);

            // Execute a transaction, replacing any existing fragment
            // with this one inside the frame.
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();
        }

    } else {
        // Otherwise we need to launch a new activity to display
        // the dialog fragment with selected text.
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("index", index);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But here, I didn't add any fragment tags in my xml. In which XML I can add Fragment tag and which one? From above code,  ft.replace(R.id.details, details); Here details is nothing but fragment tag id. Can any advice..

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'd navigate from a fragment to a new one:

```
Fragment fragment = new FragNew();
    FragmentManager fm = this.getActivity().getFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
```

Hope this helps.